# Incorrect syntax near ',' when i call ExecuteScalar

Tags: c#, sql, sqlcommand

I have a question. I know there are some topic which are simillar to this question, but I couldn´t find answer in this topics, so this is which I need help.
I got this query:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO InterniLozniListS3_Hlavicka(Stredisko, DatumNakladky, SmenaNakladky, HodNakladky, 
                           NaklPredak, CisloLL, SpzVozuTahace, SpzVozuNavesu, Mpz, Mpz2, NaprTlak, TaraNova, Unosnost, PocetNaprav, StaniceUrceni,
                           , PrijemceZbozi, DatNarozeni, JmenoAPrijmeni, Podpis, Vyhotovil, Vysilal, Kod, UvolnenoPrijmeni, UvolnenoTelefon, UvolnenoPlaceno) 
                           OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
                           VALUES
                            (@stredisko, @datumNakladky, @smenaNakladky, @hodNakladky, @naklPredak, @cisloLL, @spzVozuTahace, 
                            @spzVozuNavesu, @mpz, @mpz2, @naprTlak, @taraNova, @unosnost, @pocetNapr, @staniceUrceni,@prijemceZbozi,
                            @datNarozeni, @jmenoAPrijmeni, @Podpis, @Vyhotovil, @Vysilal, @Kod, @uvolnenoPrijmeni, @UvolnenoTelefon, @UvolnenoPlaceno)
                          ;", connection);
```

I think I have this INSERT right, but if I start application and debug it ends here

```
    return long.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

I really dont know where is mistake :/.

Comment: You have a comma at the end of one line and also at the start of the next line, remove one of them.

Comment: I believe you should do this with questions marks.

Comment: `StaniceUrceni,  , PrijemceZbozi`

Comment: @SayusiAndo If you mean "write a question using the question mark", then yes, probably, but if you mean to use question marks for parameters, then no, this is SQL Server.

Comment: in the 2nd line you a comma and in the start of the 3rd do you have another comma
`StaniceUrceni,
                           , PrijemceZbozi`

Comment: And do not write applications in Czech, vole! ;-)

Comment: @styx - thank you :D im such a idiot ..

Comment: @Honzajscz - Máme interní systém tak si to můžeme dovolit! :D

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen :D Nope, [Parameter binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/binding-parameters-odbc?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: @SayusiAndo Then he's using the right syntax (in that regard).

Comment: Re your title: this is a syntax error in SQL, not in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, you have a comma at the end of a line and at the beginning of the next:

```
StaniceUrceni,
, PrijemceZbozi
```

So you should always use the same comma strategy, either at the beginning or end:

```
string sql = @"
INSERT INTO InterniLozniListS3_Hlavicka(
    Stredisko,  DatumNakladky,  SmenaNakladky, HodNakladky, NaklPredak, 
    CisloLL, SpzVozuTahace, SpzVozuNavesu, Mpz, Mpz2, NaprTlak, TaraNova, 
    Unosnost, PocetNaprav, StaniceUrceni, PrijemceZbozi, DatNarozeni, 
    JmenoAPrijmeni, Podpis, Vyhotovil, Vysilal, Kod, UvolnenoPrijmeni, 
    UvolnenoTelefon, UvolnenoPlaceno) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
VALUES (
    @stredisko, @datumNakladky, @smenaNakladky, @hodNakladky, @naklPredak, 
    @cisloLL, @spzVozuTahace, @spzVozuNavesu, @mpz, @mpz2, @naprTlak, @taraNova,
    @unosnost, @pocetNapr, @staniceUrceni,@prijemceZbozi, @datNarozeni, 
    @jmenoAPrijmeni, @Podpis, @Vyhotovil, @Vysilal, @Kod, @uvolnenoPrijmeni, 
    @UvolnenoTelefon, @UvolnenoPlaceno);"
```

As you see it's also helpful to avoid scrolling horitontally.

```
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conection))
{
    return (long) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: Thank you , that solved my problem :) Thank you pretty much.

Answer (score 0):

another and better working approach.

**In Sql database engine, create a stored procedure, like:**

```
//Defining random datatypes to the parameters as i don't know which should be of which DataType.
    create proc sp_InsertUpdate_InterniLozniListS3_Hlavicka
    @stredisko int,
    @datumNakladky varchar(255), 
    @smenaNakladky varchar(255), 
    @hodNakladky varchar(255), 
    @naklPredak varchar(255), 
    @cisloLL varchar(255),
    @spzVozuTahace varchar(255), 
    @spzVozuNavesu varchar(255), 
    @mpz varchar(255), 
    @mpz2 varchar(255), 
    @naprTlak varchar(255), 
    @taraNova varchar(255),
    @unosnost varchar(255), 
    @pocetNapr varchar(255), 
    @staniceUrceni varchar(255),
    @prijemceZbozi varchar(255), 
    @datNarozeni varchar(255), 
    @jmenoAPrijmeni varchar(255), 
    @Podpis varchar(255), 
    @Vyhotovil varchar(255), 
    @Vysilal varchar(255), 
    @Kod varchar(255), 
    @uvolnenoPrijmeni varchar(255), 
    @UvolnenoTelefon varchar(255), 
    @UvolnenoPlaceno  varchar(255)
    as 
    begin
    if(@stredisko == 0) //Assuming this is  Primary key and identity column of the table
    begin
         INSERT INTO InterniLozniListS3_Hlavicka(
        Stredisko,  DatumNakladky,  SmenaNakladky, HodNakladky, NaklPredak, 
        CisloLL, SpzVozuTahace, SpzVozuNavesu, Mpz, Mpz2, NaprTlak, TaraNova, 
        Unosnost, PocetNaprav, StaniceUrceni, PrijemceZbozi, DatNarozeni, 
        JmenoAPrijmeni, Podpis, Vyhotovil, Vysilal, Kod, UvolnenoPrijmeni, 
        UvolnenoTelefon, UvolnenoPlaceno) 
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
    VALUES (
        @stredisko, @datumNakladky, @smenaNakladky, @hodNakladky, @naklPredak, 
        @cisloLL, @spzVozuTahace, @spzVozuNavesu, @mpz, @mpz2, @naprTlak, @taraNova,
        @unosnost, @pocetNapr, @staniceUrceni,@prijemceZbozi, @datNarozeni, 
        @jmenoAPrijmeni, @Podpis, @Vyhotovil, @Vysilal, @Kod, @uvolnenoPrijmeni, 
        @UvolnenoTelefon, @UvolnenoPlaceno);"
    end
    else
    begin
        //Update query here
    end
end
```

**Then, in your C# code**

```
SqlParameter[] param = new {
       new SqlParameter("@stredisko",ValueHereForThisParam),
       //add rest the required params here
}

SqlConnection oCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
SqlCommand oCom = new SqlCommand();
oCom.Connection =  oCon;
oCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
oCom.CommandText = "sp_InsertUpdate_InterniLozniListS3_Hlavicka";
oCom.Parameters.AddRange(param )
oCon.Open();
int i = oCom.ExecuteScalar(); //Will return the added
oCon.Close();
```